# How can I stream a mp4 video file as input for audio/video loopback devices in macos?

Tags: macos, audio, video, webcam, streaming

In Linux, we can use ffmpeg to stream a video file as inputs to virtual audio/video devices emulated using v4l2loopback & snd-aloop drivers.

**LINUX**

> **ffmpeg -i /home/user/downloads/myvideo.mp4 -map 0:0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0 -map 0:1 -f alsa hw:Loopback,0**

The above command will pass the audio & video streams from the mp4 file to [v4l2loopback webcam](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopbackproject.org/wiki/Main_Page) & [alsa loopback card](https://alsa-) respectively.

I want to achieve the same thing on MacOS VM running in virtualbox using [webcamoid's akvcam virtual webcam driver](https://webcamoid.github.io/) & [soundflower loopback card](https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/wiki) which are identified via avfoundation as list below:

```bash
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] [0] Testcam1 (akvcam/video0)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] [0] Soundflower (2ch)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f2d3e802560] [1] Soundflower (64ch)
```

Though it doesn't straight forward like Linux, I had tried the following to make it happen, but was not successful :

**MACOS**

> **ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/myvideo.mp4 -f avfoundation -video_device_index 0 -audio_device_index 0**

resulted in this: one output file is must be specified to write the output

The examples I came across in the web are just meant to be capturing audio/video through the devices as like the one here :

**Example Found:-**

> **ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format bgr0 -i "0:0" out.avi**

But I need the command to perform the thing in the reverse way to broadcast it in a web conference. Any guidance will be highly appreciated...

Comment: This may be hardware-dependent: "MacOS VM running in virtualbox" -> on which host system are you running this?

Comment: The Mac VM has been running on VMware ESXi hypervisor installed on a bare-metal server.